# Why is my code not printing anything to stdout?

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate the average of a student's marks:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int mark;
        int countTotal = 0;  // to count the number of entered marks
        int avg = 0;        // to calculate the total average
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your marks: ");
        String Name = Scan.next();

        while (Scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            mark = Scan.nextInt();
            countTotal++;

            avg = avg + ((mark - avg) / countTotal);
        }


        System.out.print( Name + "  " + avg );
    } 
}
```

Comment: Note: according to [Sun Java Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html) variable identifiers should start with *lowercase*. I.e. `Scan` and `Name` should be `scan` and `name`.

Comment: Shouldn't "Enter your average" actually be "Enter your marks"?

Comment: yup exactly,,, sorry typing mistake...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses two `Scanner` (as suggested in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753442/how-do-i-add-an-average-when-its-entered-from-user-input/2753468#2753468)).

- `Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);` scans user's input
- `Scanner scores = new Scanner(stdin.nextLine());` scans the line containing the scores

Note also that it uses a much simpler and more readable formula for computing the average.

```
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your average: ");
        String name = stdin.next();

        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        Scanner scores = new Scanner(stdin.nextLine());
        while (scores.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += scores.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        double avg = 1D * sum / count;
        System.out.print(name + "  " + avg);
```

Sample output:

```
Enter your average: Joe 1 2 3
Joe  2.0
```

Comment: I should chagne `System.out.print(name + ....);` to `println`

Comment: The average formula I gave WM is the same one used in apache math:
http://commons.apache.org/math/api-1.0/org/apache/commons/math/stat/descriptive/moment/Mean.html

Answer (score 4):

Because it's still sitting in the `while` loop, waiting for an instruction to break out of the loop.

Here's a [Sun tutorial on the subject](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). The course materials you got should also contain this information by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In my previous post ([previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753442/how-do-i-add-an-average-when-its-entered-from-user-input/2753682#2753682)) I indicated that you need to press Ctrl+D after you are done inputting numbers. Ctrl+D signals to your program that there is no more input.

Try entering:

WM 1 2 3 6

Then press Ctrl+D

Comment: That's more a workaround than a solution. I'm not sure if he get extra points for that.

Comment: yea @Balus is right,,  and btw it didnt work out,, i want it to work when pressing enter but still not printing..

Comment: You'll need to change your `while` statement to break on an empty new line. Check the methods provided by `Scanner`. Or consult your course materials, tutor and/or classmates. There they are for.

Comment: @WM: read my answer again, especially the hint about `Scanner` scanning a string which is a line from another `Scanner`.

Comment: i didnt get what you stated sorry,,

Comment: @WM: see my answer here on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753876/why-is-my-code-not-printing-anything-to-stdout/2753964#2753964

Answer (score 0):

You should use getline and accept an "exit" string. String.split and some of the Integer.valueOf stuff makes parsing numbers from string literals written in very easy in Java.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Average{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int mark = 0;
    int countTotal = 0;  // to count the number of entered marks
    int avg = 0;        // to calculate the total average
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter student name: ");
    String name = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter marks one by one?");


    while(scan.hasNextInt()){

        int tempMark = scan.nextInt();
        mark += tempMark;
        countTotal+=1;

        System.out.println("If you are done with mark, type \"Done!\"");
    }

    avg = mark/countTotal;

    System.out.print( name + "  " + avg );
}
```

}