# Write a program that allows the user to enter a string and then prints the letters of the String separated by comma

Tags: java

The output is always a String, for example `H,E,L,L,O,`. How could I limit the commas? I want the commas only between letters, for example `H,E,L,L,O`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.lang.String;

public class forLoop 

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        String Str1 = Scan.next();

       String newString="";
       String Str2 ="";
        for (int i=0; i < Str1.length(); i++)
        {
                newString = Str1.charAt(i) + ",";

                Str2 = Str2 + newString;  

        }
       System.out.print(Str2);

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you wanting this to do?

Comment: [Once again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753876/why-is-my-code-not-printing-anything-to-stdout#comment-2784801), try to adhere the [Sun Java Naming Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html) as much as possible if you don't want to lose points. Variable identifiers ought to start with lowercase. `Scan` and `Str2` are invalid. Also, classnames ought to start with uppercase. `forLoop` is invalid.

Comment: Using the standard naming conventions is good practice, sure, but you can't necessarily say the poster is going to lose points on the assignment for not following them. That's entirely up to the grader and the specifications of the assignment. (And I would call it unconventional and discouraged, but not invalid)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753313/write-a-program-that-allows-the-user-to-enter-a-string-and-then-prints-the-letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I see is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String Str1 = Scan.nextLine();

   String newString="";
   String Str2 ="";
    for (int i=0; i < Str1.length()-1; i++)
    {
            newString = Str1.charAt(i) + ",";

            Str2 = Str2 + newString;

    }
   Str2 = Str2 + Str1.charAt(Str1.length()-1);
   System.out.println(Str2);
}
```

The output it will give is :

```
run:
Enter a string: Hello world
H,e,l,l,o, ,w,o,r,l,d
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Though I will highly recommend learning regular expression as suggested by @Roman. Till then this will do the trick. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework I'll help you out a little without giving the answer:

If you want the output to only be inbetween letters IE: A,B,C instead of A,B,C,  which is what I imagine you are asking about.  Then you need to look at your for loop and check the boundary conditions.

Comment: if i changed the loop to  Str1.length()-1,,, it will give me A,B, excluding the C...

Comment: What I mean is check the condition at which you append a comma

Comment: Try using an if statement inside your loop.

Comment: or just change your output when you get out of the loop (you know it always ends in a comma, so....)

Answer (score 0):

Just don't append the comma when the **last** item of the loop is to be appended. You have the item index by `i` and the string length by `Str2.length()`. Just do the primary school math with a lesser-than or a greater-than operator in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try regular expressions:

```
String input = scanner.next();
String output = input.replaceAll(".", "$0,");
```

With spaces it would be a bit easier since you don't need to abandon last 'odd' comma:

```
output = output.substring (0, ouput.length() - 2);
```

Comment: I didnt say it was, the down vote was because of an added layer of complexity that is not needed at this point in the learning process

Comment: It's not pedantry if the answer is unnecessarily complex, more confusing and less useful to the asker.

Comment: I can only suppose that none of you both know this solution. Anyway, let it be here just for the sake of some variety in answers.

Comment: @Roman: FWIW, I also gave a regex-solution the first time OP asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753313/write-a-program-that-allows-the-user-to-enter-a-string-and-then-prints-the-letter/2753331#2753331

Answer (score 0):

When you've figured out the loop-solution, you could try the following ;)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("HELLO".toCharArray()).replaceAll("[\\[ \\]]", ""));
```

Comment: If you're doing `replaceAll`, might as well do it without the `Arrays.toString/toCharArray`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753313/write-a-program-that-allows-the-user-to-enter-a-string-and-then-prints-the-letter/2753331#2753331

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should be instructive. It shows:

- How to use [`StringBuilder`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for building strings
- How to process each `char` in a `String` using an explicit index

  - How to detect if it's the first/last iteration for special processing

---

```
    String s = "HELLO";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (i == 0) { // first
            sb.append("(" + ch + ")");
        } else if (i == s.length() - 1) { // last
            sb.append("<" + ch + ">");
        } else { // everything in between
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    // prints "(H)ell<O>"
```